# collection view cell width is not correct

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

after update to ios 12 and xcode 10 the collectionView with cell sizeing cell does not work correctly anymore.

i have this layout in xcode

[image]

the view is like this.

[image]

and this is how it looks now.

[image]

i have tried to set the collectionview view a widht constraint and modified in the

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
cell.widthConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the wrong method to set the cells size.
 Instead of `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` use  `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemHeight = 60
    let itemWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
```

Also, you can set up items size using `Interface Builder`s `Size Inspector`, but in that case, the size of your cells will be absolute. If you want it to be `1/3` of screen width, you need to use the layout delegate.